# Is there a way in TinyMCE if I type **MY-TEXT** then it makes it bold?

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce, textarea, wysiwyg

Is there a way in TinyMCE if I type **MY-TEXT** then it makes it bold? or if I enter **My Text** manually then it converts to bold automatically?

I tried adding  tag but that does not work

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your configrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textpattern` plugin will do what you want:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/textpattern/

In your screenshot you appear to be trying to type HTML into the WYSISYG view of TinyMCE - that won't work.  There is a `code` plugin that you can use to insert HTML code into TinyMCE.

One last note - you appear to be using TinyMCE 4 and that is no longer a supported release of TinyMCE after 31-Dec-2020 so you may want to look at moving to TinyMCE 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works like a charm. And yes, I've updated to TinyMCE v5. Thanks!